# Redirect file into stdin as an option of a command

Tags: command-line, bash

I am running a command (tree_doctor) that has an option (--prune), which takes comma-separated list as input (e.g., A,B,C). I can get desired output with

```
tree_doctor --prune A,B,C --other_option
```

But I want to input the A,B,C from a file (list.ls) that contains A,B,C inside and I failed with:

```
tree_doctor --prune list.ls --other_option
tree_doctor --prune < list.ls --other_option
tree_doctor --prune <(cat list.ls) --other_option
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work with the following syntax:

```
tree_doctor --prune "$(cat list.ls)" --other_option
```

`list.ls` contains the string 'A,B,C' for your example.

Comment: That works very well. Thank you!